# Execute python script with CLI arguments via winexe

Tags: python, linux, windows, arguments, winexe

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to execute (from my Linux machine) a python script, which takes arguments from CLI in order to run properly.
The script located on my Windows machine, and I'm trying to do this by using winexe.

```
./winexe -A localConfig //MyServer 'cmd.exe /c "cd C:/scriptDirectory & python MyPythonScript --user sami --day sunday --age 5"
```

What happens is that when I execute the command above, MyPythonScript is running but completely ignore the arguments that I'm passing via the CLI.
Any suggestions?

Here is part of the code that accepts the arguments:

```
argsLen = len(sys.argv)
if argsLen > 1:
    user = sys.argv[2]
    day = sys.argv[4]
    age = sys.argv[6]
else:
    user = myUser
    day = myDay
    age = myAge
```

You help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code that accepts the arguments in your python script?

Comment: Sure , my original post was edited

Comment: Try adding a debug print at the beginning of your python script, to show what arguments it gets.